# Async pipe vs. Subscribe. Why is async pipe version slower?

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I've created an app to search employes that use observables.
It's very simple:
template for subscribe

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-6 g-2">
    <ng-container *ngIf="emps.length">
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let emp of emps">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img *ngIf="emp.image" [src]="emp.image" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <span *ngIf="emp.actived" class="badge rounded-pill bg-success"
                            style="position: absolute;top: 2px;right: 2px;">&#10003;
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{emp.name| uppercase}}</h5>
                    <!-- <pre class="card-text">{{emp.phones}}</pre> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container> 
</div>
```

Component:

```js
emps: IToList[] = [];

change(){//e: HTMLInputElement) {
  this.service.getPeople(this.searchTerm).pipe(
     map(data => data.map(d => {
         let c = new Person(d._id, d.actived, d.name, d.phones, d.image);
         return c.getPerson();
     }))
  ).subscribe(data=>this.emps=data);
}
```

It works fine for me:

[image]

The async pipe version.
template:

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-6 g-2">
    <ng-container *ngIf="people$|async as emps">
        <div class="col" *ngFor="let emp of emps">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img *ngIf="emp.image" [src]="emp.image" class="card-img-top" alt="image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <span *ngIf="emp.actived" class="badge rounded-pill bg-success"
                            style="position: absolute;top: 2px;right: 2px;">&#10003;
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{emp.name | uppercase}}</h5>
                    <!-- <pre class="card-text">{{emp.phones}}</pre> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container> 
</div>
```

Component:

```js
people$!: Observable<IToList[]>;
      
change(){//e: HTMLInputElement) {
   this.people$ = this.service.getPeople(this.searchTerm).pipe(
      map(data => data.map(d => {
           let c = new Person(d._id, d.attivo, d.nominativo, d.telefoni, d.immagine);
           return c.getPerson();
      }))
  ); 
}
```

[image]

Why is the app more responsive when I'm manually subscribing instead of using an async pipe?

Updated 10/06/2022

The image src is a base64 string and its size is 3mb.

Comment: Because async/await stops the JS main thread while executing the instructions that are inside the function. So, while doing it,  DOM rendering is stuck.

Comment: I don't recommend re-assigning the value to `this.people$` every time change is called. place your pipe on `people$` and call `sub.next()` of which `people$ = this.sub.asObservable().pipe(...)`

Comment: I don't see any noticeable difference in speed between both examples. The only difference I see is the white flickering in the async version, but that's because you are reassigning the `people$` property after each change.

Comment: to @GetOffMyLawn. it's no clear to me. wath's this.sub?

Comment: @Kraken see my example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-search-without-reassign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use async Pipe you will use `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in `OnPush` it will improve your performance.

Async pipe it`s better in most of the cases because it is in charge to handle  the subscription and unsuscription and notify which reactive part of the code is going to be rendered. Also you prevent possible memory leaks.

Even you can remove the ngif and the container where is the main subscription just by adding the async pipe in the `*ngFor="let emp of (people$ | async)"`

***************************** Edit ********************************************

The main problem in you code that is mentioned by **@Get Off My Lawn**.
Each time the search term change your observable is been recreated and it is the difference between with your 2 examples.

What You can do is in the ngOninit add the people$ observable with the form control of the search input then adding a switchMap operator to execute the service call then you will have the same observable and subscription always

```
ngOnini{
  this.people$ = this.form.get('searchInput').valueChanges.pipe(
   switchMap(searchTerm => this.service.getPeople(this.searchTerm)),
   map(data => => data.map(d => {
     let c = new Person(d._id, d.actived, d.name, d.phones, d.image);
     return c.getPerson();
   }))
  );
}
```

Comment: I noted that if I use changedetection on push, the data is rendered from the second character.
Probably I wrong something

Comment: What you mean with second character ?

Comment: Ok, but the behavior doesn't change when I type in the search box

Comment: I just modify my post try to do that if you dont have your input with a control form just add it to have access to the value changes observable.

Comment: I'm gratiful for your help too